# If $D$ is dense in $X$, and $Y\subset X$, what conditions on $Y$ ensure that $D\cap Y$ is dense in $Y$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Suppose that $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space, $D\subset X$ is dense in $X$ and $Y\subset X$. [It can be shown](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_of_dense_subset_with_open_subset_is_dense_in_the_open_subset) that if $Y$ is open, then $D\cap Y$ is dense in $Y$ (using the subset topology). However, $Y$ being open is not necessary, since, for example, the set of non-negative rationals is dense in the set of non-negative reals.

My question is: Are there necessary and sufficient conditions on $Y$ so that $D\cap Y$ is dense in $Y$? If not, what other sufficient conditions are there?

If it allows us to make stronger statements, please substitute $(X,\tau)$ with some normed space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a topological space and $Y \subset X$, then the following are equivalent

1. $D \cap Y$ is dense in $Y$ whenever $D$ is dense in $X$
2. $Y$ has a dense interior, that is $Y \subset \operatorname{Cl} \operatorname{Int} Y$

The implication $2 \implies 1$ is an obvious extension of the result you quoted; the other direction can be obtained by considering the case
$D = X\setminus Y \cup \operatorname{Int} Y$.

Answer (score 2):

I am unaware of any necessary and sufficient conditions. Alternate sufficient conditions include:

- $D\subseteq Y$
- $D\cap Y$ is dense in $X$