# Is $U\cap C$ dense in $C$?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a topological space, $C$ is a closed subset of $X$, $U$ is an open subset of $X$ and $U$ is dense in $X$, is $U\cap C$ dense in $C$?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? Please show your work. Perhaps consider $[0,1)=U$ in $[0,1]=X$, and $C = \{0,1\}$. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521396/if-d-is-dense-in-x-and-y-subset-x-what-conditions-on-y-ensure-that-d?rq=1) post.

Comment: The issue here is that $\overline{U\cap C}$ does not necessarily
equal to $\overline{U}\cap C$ (e.g., the example by @PedroTamaroff).

Comment: $C=X-U$ gives rise to many counterexamples

Comment: A different and often-used result is that if $D$ is dense in $X$ and $U$ is open in $X$ then $D\cap U$ is dense in $U$, and  $Cl_X(U)=Cl_X(D\cap U).$

Answer (score 3):

No, take $C=\mathbb{Z}$ (closed in $X=\mathbb{R}$ (usual topology)) and $U = \mathbb{R}\setminus{Z}$ which is open and dense. $C \cap U=\emptyset$ is not dense in $C$.

Any space with a closed set $C$ with empty interior (and $U$ its complement) will do.

Answer (score 2):

This is true if and only if $C$ is the closure of its interior. Such sets are called *regular closed sets*.

Indeed, if $C=\overline{V}$ for some open $V$, then $U\cap V$ is dense in $V$, and hence in $C$, so $U\cap C\supseteq U\cap V$ is dense in $C$. (Note that we do not really use the assumption that $U$ is open --- only density matters.)

Otherwise, if $C$ is not the closure of its interior, $U=(X\setminus C)\cup \operatorname{int}(C)$ is open and dense, and $U\cap C=\operatorname{int}(C)$, so $U\cap C$ is not dense in $C$.