# Let $U\subset X$ be a subspace of a topological space $X$ such that $U\cap S$ is dense in $U$ for every $S\subset X$ dense in $X$. Is $U$ open?

Tags: general-topology

It is a basic fact from general topology that if $U\subset X$ is open, then $S\cap U$ is dense in $U$ for every $S\subset X$ dense in $X$. My question is about the recriprocal:

1. Is it true for every topological space $X$?
2. If not, this class of subsets receives some special name? What are the main examples (besides open sets) and properties of them?
3. Under which conditions on $X$ one can ensure that it holds?

Thanks.

P.S: in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/523110/756647) answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521396/if-d-is-dense-in-x-and-y-subset-x-what-conditions-on-y-ensure-that-d?rq=1) question we have a characterization for the subsets $S$ satisfying the desired property: are those which have dense interior.

P.S2: recall that a subset $S\subset X$ is *nowhere dense* if it has an empty interior. The complement of every  nowhere dense subsets has dense interior - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set). Actually, a $S$ has dense interior (and therefore is in the class that I described) iff it is the complement of some nowhere dense subset. A set which is a countable intersection of sets with dense interior is called *comeagre* - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set).

Comment: Just a guess: What about $U = \mathbb{R} \setminus (0, 1)$?

Comment: Thanks for this counterexample! Could you say something about the second question?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not aware of a name for the class of subspaces.

Comment: This is equivalent to $\operatorname{int} U$ being dense in $U$. I'm not aware of a name for such sets.

Comment: Thanks. I added this in an edit of the question.

Comment: @TheoBendit: Such sets are called *semi-open* sets: a set $A$ is semi-open iff there is an open set $U$ such that $U\subseteq A\subseteq\operatorname{cl}U$.